# Logitech Ergo M575 Mouse - (Newly) Experiencing Frequent Lag/Stuttering

Tags: mouse, logitech

I have a Logitech Ergo M575 Trackball mouse that I have been using for about 6 months.  I primarily use it on Bluetooth (vs. the included USB receiver).  I have had no problems with this device up until today.

I am experiencing frequent lag/stutter with this mouse.  Moving the trackball does not move the mouse pointer, clicking/scrolling Mouse 1, 2, 3 buttons do nothing.  This seems to be happening between every 30 seconds to 2 minutes and lasting roughly 10-15 seconds.

Using the trackpad on my laptop or another mouse causes no problem.  Using the M575 on other computers, I observe the same issues.

I have tried everything I can think of or found online.

1. I have replaced the battery and checked the battery level on the Logi Options + application and can see that it is fully charged.
2. I have uninstalled and reinstalled the drivers (fresh from Logitech).
3. I have removed the trackball and cleaned out the dust/debris.
4. I have removed and re-added the mouse to my laptop's Bluetooth connections.
5. I have checked the mouse in Device Manager and updated/refreshed drivers (automatically) to no avail.

This mouse, as stated, is relatively new and should not be experiencing such a severe lack of function.  Any advice or information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have dual monitors going? If so, check that the refresh rates of all connected monitors match. That was the cause for me, and it solved it for a while until a recent Windows 11 update started up the problem again.

Comment: I am running dual monitors, and after checking both have a refresh rate of 60Hz.  I may have to ensure they align with my laptop as well.